# Python -Switch state of turtle pen using single keypress

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics

While writing a simple drawing program, I ran into a problem; I want to use the space key to switch the state of the pen from up to down and vice versa.

Of course this could be achieved with an

```
if event.char == "a key:"
    pen.penup()
elif event.char == "another key":
    pen.pendown()
```

However this is messy, and not what I am looking for, I want a single key to switch the pen position-

```
Pseudo-
if event.char == "space":
    if pen.position == up:
        pen.pendown()
    else:
        pen.penup()
```

Is there a method for doing this?
For example with a tkinter widget you have

```
widgetName.cget("text")
```

If the widget 'widgetName' is a widget with a text option, this will return the string used as the text option.

What I need is either a `pen.switchstate()` or a `pen.cget("state")`

Thanks to anyone who can offer some help.

Edit:
As I fixed the problem ,here is the link to the documentation-
https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/turtle.html#turtle.isdown

`.isdown()` will either return True or False, which can be used to make the decision.

Comment: if event.char == "a key:"
    pen.penup()
elif event.char == "another key":
    pen.penup()     
Is there a typo? Should the last line be pen.pendown()?

Comment: Yes that was, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I clearly didn't look hard enough. Right there in the documentation is `pen.isdown()`
Sorry, feel free to delete the question.

Comment: You can accept your answer or delete the question. I would advise keeping it and add a link to the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I will accept my answer soon, however I have to wait two days to do it. Will add the documentation